# MySQL Select rows with same id but different multiple values in another colum

Tags: mysql

Maybe my question will be silly, but i'm new to Mysql

I have a table with user_id and some interest.

```
+------+------+
|userID|Inter |
+------+------+
|1     |sport |
+------+------+
|2     |it    |
+------+------+
|3     |game  |
+------+------+
|1     |it    |
+------+------+
|1     |game  |
+------+------+
|3     |it    |
+------+------+
|3     |sport |
+------+------+
```

Amount of interests can be huge(let say 20 or whatever)

Now i need to find all userId's that have interests `it, game, sport`;

Of course simple AND wont work as because of different rows.

So my question will be how to do it, so the output will be

```
+------+
|userID|
+------+
|1     |
+------+
|3     |
+------+
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it by using GROUP BY and COUNT(*)

> ```
> create table users (user_id int, interest varchar(20));
> ```

> ```
> insert into users values(1, 'sport');
> insert into users values(2, 'it');
> insert into users values(3, 'game');
> insert into users values(1, 'it');
> insert into users values(1, 'game');
> insert into users values(3, 'it');
> insert into users values(3, 'sport');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT user_id
> FROM   users
> WHERE  interest IN ('game', 'it', 'sport')
> GROUP BY user_id
> HAVING count(*) = 3;
> ```
>
> ```
> | user_id |
> | ------: |
> |       1 |
> |       3 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=dc590dd5bca9c808c4fc9d2062d7765f)*

Comment: Omg.. So easy and whats important without joins. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad to help

Comment: Btw..One more small question..This query still be effective on huge datasets like 10 millions records and so on? Thank you

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk I think so, but have one index on interest?

Comment: *"whats important without joins"*: There are several solution for this kind of problems. Many of them use joins - and are often faster than the GROUP BY - HAVING method ;)

Comment: If you really have only those two columns, the query will always be a table scan, and no index will help.